# Based on given number of bins distribute column data into equal average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe where data is like & max bins where we want to distribute data is 3 bins

| x | count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 5 |
| d | 7 |
| e | 9 |

So sum will be of `count` will be 26 we need to distribute into 3 bins, which averages as 8.66 so each bin should have count close to 8 or 9

| cluster_id | group |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {e} |
| 1 | {d,a} |
| 2 | {c,b} |

Comment: Sounds like [multi knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem)

Comment: Yeah looking for a way to do it using pandas & python if possible

Comment: There are many libraries that achieve this ;)

Comment: @mozway Yes but I have another dimension of x column, in some cases 2 values in x will have same count.

Comment: Then you should focus your question on a single problem.

Comment: @mozway Now it's focused on one problem remove the merging of results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am able to figure it out I used bin packing solution to work on it
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

```
>>> import binpacking
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['x']= ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> df['count']=[2,3,5,7,9]
>>> df
   x  count
0  a      2
1  b      3
2  c      5
3  d      7
4  e      9
>>> map_exe_count = df.set_index('x').to_dict()['count']
>>> groups = binpacking.to_constant_bin_number(map_exe_count, bins)
>>> exes_per_bin = [list(group.keys()) for group in groups if len(group.keys()) > 0]
>>> exes_per_bin
[['e'], ['d', 'a'], ['c', 'b']]
```